# xCode / declaring Static Methods in class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, static-methods

Anyone know how I can declare a static method for an xcode class and then use it in my project?

I want to create a Common.h class and then do something like this in one of .m file

Common.MyStaticMethod();

I dont want to have to instantiate and instance of Common

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You will declare a class level method in Objective-C by using "+" before the method declaration.

```
// in Common.h
+ (void)myStaticMethod;

// call is from anywhere
[Common myStaticMethod]
```

That is, a "-" before method declaration means instance methods and "+" means class level method which are not related with any particular instance of the class.

Comment: Class methods are not static in Objective-C; they're resolved dynamically just like instance methods. The Objective-C equivalent of a static method is a C function, rather than a class method.

Comment: Ya, class is also an object in obj-c. Thats why in my answer I have  specified them as class method, not static method. By I guess this is what Vilasack is wanting.